# How to hide ID field in MVC4 view

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC4. I have a form for displaying user roles and a link for editing.
This template is created by entity scaffold.

Whenver user clicks edit link a jquery modal popup displays for editing. The form contains 2 fields ID and User Role .

I wished not to display the Id part so i commented the ID part display  . But after updating i will get the error like

```
 Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of   
rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.  
Refresh ObjectStateManager entries
```

I then debugged and found the ID was 0. So I tritd with displaying ID It worked.
why is this happening. How can I dispaly and edit form without ID field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden input for the ID property in your form

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
```

or add a route value in the form ([refer all the overloads here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx))

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName", new { ID = Model.ID })`
```

Comment: Ok that solved my problem.
Since am in learning phase i would like to know second option.
"Adding a route value in form" what does that mean

Comment: I'll update the answer in a mement (but I don't know your controller and action names so you will need to fill in the blanks)